# Unity getting an object to pass through another object but still trigger collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

basicaly i need an object to be able to pass through an object just like as if it was a trigger, but still detect it as a colision becouse of the way i made hitting enemies work (or a way to get physics2d.overlapboxall to detect triggers), here is the code for my weapon attack and the enemy i need to pass through the player but also do damage to the player.

```
 if (AttackDelay <= 0)
            { //attacking
                Collider2D[] EnemiesToDmg = Physics2D.OverlapBoxAll(AttackPos.position,new Vector2(AttackRangeX,AttackRangeY),0, WhatIsEnemy);
                for (int i = 0; i < EnemiesToDmg.Length; i++)
                {EnemiesToDmg[i].GetComponent<Health>().takeDamage(AttackDamage);}
```

and for the enemy

```
    void FixedUpdate()
    {


        RotateAndMove(target2);
        if (AttackRecharge<=AttackRechargeMax)
        {
            AttackRecharge += Time.deltaTime;
        }


    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.layer==10)
        {
            player.gameObject.GetComponent<Health>().takeDamage(20);
        }
        if(collision.gameObject.transform==target2)
        {


           if (!IsVisible)
            {
                 target2.position = player.position + (player.position - transform.position) / 5;
            }
           else
            {
                TeleportToCamera(target2);
            }

        }


    }
```

Comment: That’s exactly what triggers are. Colliders that you can move in

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments this is exactly what `isTrigger` is for.
You can change this [in code](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider-isTrigger.html) like this:

```
Collider.isTrigger = true;
```

Or in the editor with this tickbox:
[image]

This will allow you to use code such as `OnTriggerEnter` and will make your game object be able to be passed through